# prove determinant of rotation matrix is -1 or 1

Tags: determinant, rotations

Rotation matrix determinant is 1 or -1.How can prove this generally.

Assuming that rotation can be around every axis.

Comment: Besides any formal proof, there is some nice intuition here. If you think about the determinant as related to a volume, then a pure rotation does not alter this volume, hence the determinant is $1$.

Comment: @WalterJ . Thank you for answer. but if we consider rotation for change coordinate system it will be logical.

Comment: How do you define *rotation matrix*?

Answer (score 4):

If the rotation is by an angle that is a rational multiple of $\pi$, then a finite power of it  is the identity, hence $1=\det I=\det A^m=(\det A)^m$.
For the general case, note that $\det$ is continuous and rotations by rational angles are a dense subset.

Comment: Thank you for the answer . This is general rule and i,m looking prove for -1 part especially in change coordinate system

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean ratations in $\mathbb{R}^3$, here. Actually, the determinant is alway $1$. To see why, let $v_1$ be a non-null vector of the axis. Let $v_2$ and $v_3$ be two vectors orthogonal to $v_1$ which are also orthogonal to each other. Then, if $r$ is your rotation, there is some $\theta\in\mathbb R$ such that $r(v_2)=\cos(\theta)v_2+\sin(\theta)v_3$ and that $r(v_3)=-\sin(\theta)v_2+\cos(\theta)v_3$. Therefore, the matrix of $r$ with respect to the basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\0&\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix},$$whose determinant is $1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer . for convert between 2 coordinate system -1 May happen.